# When we should go for Java Connection Architecture (JCA) over REST

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jca

Popular Enterprise information systems (EIS) provide REST API and JCA to integrate with Java EE web applications. When REST API is avialable, why & when we should go for JCA based integration ?

For example, Salesforce provides excellent REST API(s). Also there are developers who develop JCA connectors for Salesforce, [like this](https://github.com/mulesoft/salesforce-connector). I am unable to justify why I should go for JCA when REST is so flexible & easy to integrate with any application.

Comment: Why would you think you should, out of interest? JCA is for legacy systems, so I'd be curious to hear the use case where it would be preferable to an easy to use REST service.

Comment: Exactly, that's my doubt. When we have REST API exposed for integration, why we should go JCA. Does it provide any promising advantage over REST?

Comment: Well, Just for Legacy many not be right. For instance, if you have your own datasource or you want custom handing, then you need to use JCA.